# Attempted relative import in non-package” even with __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

Getting error  “Attempted relative import in non-package” even with **init**.py.

```
pkg/
  __init__.py
  conf/
    core.py
    __init__.py
  scripts/
    core_script.py
    __init__.py
```

In core_script.py I have the following import statement

```
from ..conf.core import gDocsCred
```

However, when I run, I get the following error:

```
scripts$ python core_test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "core_script.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..conf.core import gDocsCred
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there because I was not using it as a package.

```
python -m pkg.scripts.core_script
```